# Learning parameters of noise and filter coefficients from data where data and noise both have Gaussian distributions

Tags: machine-learning, probability

Assume $X$ and $N$ are two sets of vectors (observations) from two different  normal distributions, where $X$ represents clean data and $N$ represents noise; and $A$ a projection matrix of a filter. the scenario is that our clean data was corrupted by a multiplicative noise via matrix $A$ and an additive noise of $N$. then:

$Y=A \times X + N$

where $Y$ are a set of projected vectors from $X$ using $A$, what are solutions to learn this projection matrix and $N$ from training data? Does the Gaussian assumption of $A, N$ and $X$ help to have a better estimation or guide to use a specific solution?

Here is matlab code for the training data, noise and a simple projection:

```
    dataVariance = .10;
    noiseVariance = .05;  
    mixtureCenters=randn(13,1);
    X=randn(13, 1000)*sqrt(dataVariance ) + repmat(mixtureCenters,1,1000);

    %N and A are unknown and we want to estimate them.
    N=randn(13, 1000)*sqrt(noiseVariance ) + repmat(mixtureCenters,1,1000);
    A=2*eye(13);

    Y=A*X+N;

    for iter=1:1000
        A_hat,N_hat = training(X_hat,X,Y);
    end
```

---

Note: if necessary, for each estimation of $A$, an error can be calculated for an estimation of $N$ using a current $A$.

For example:

```
for iterate=1:1000
  initiate A
  estimate N using current A (N=Y-A*X)
  calculate error of estimation (err=Y-A*X+N)
  update A
```

But I would prefer not to go for gradient descent approaches.

---

I should clarify that the observations of $X$ and $Y$ are time independent and in $X_i$ and $Y_i$, i is not the time. They are just different observations sampled from two normal distributions.

Comment: Have you considered trying to use a Kalman filter to estimate these parameters?

Comment: @choward hi, no. not really. I thought of multivar. linear regression though. Do you think keeping the Gaussian assumptions in mind, Kalman filter can estimate $A$ and $N$?

Comment: I think it is possible, yes. Kalman filters are based on an assumption of Gaussian noise, so it should be a decent fit for your problem.

Comment: @choward there is also something else: not only my noise $N$ are samples from a normal distribution, but also the input observations $X$ are samples from a Gaussian distribution. is this in the assumption of Kalman filtering?

Comment: @choward thank you for your answer :) I am interested in estimating nor only mean of N, but also covariance of N, in addition to estimating A. For each X, there will be a new sample of N from a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: [Also posted on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52154/755).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the way I went about formulating the problem was to essentially write the following equations:

The state that will be estimated, which is defined as a column vector, is the following:
$$w = [vec(A)^{T},\bar{N}^{T}]^{T}$$
where $\bar{N}$ is the unknown average $N$ vector and $vec(A)$ is the vectorization operator on the unknown matrix A.

Based on the definition above, one can try to estimate $w$ by the following equations:

$$w_{i+1} = w_{i} + \eta_1$$
$$y_{i} = h(w_{i},X_{k}) + \eta_2$$

where $\eta_j$ are additive white noise vectors based on some variance values, $v_j$, and $X_{k}$ represents some $k^{th}$ data point from your set of values for $X$. You can select the $X_k$ value however you want (I did it randomly). One last equation you need is the following:

$$ h(w,X) = [\hat{A},\hat{N}][X^{T},1]^{T}$$

where you extract $\hat{A}$ & $\hat{N}$ from the input $w$. Based on these equations, you can use a Kalman filter to iteratively solve this problem.

I implemented this earlier using an Unscented Kalman filter and validated it was converging to $A$ and $\bar{N}$. I will note that in the event $N$ is constant throughout all the samples, the algorithm I put together converged to $A$ and $N$ exactly (to numerical precision) within a reasonable number of iterations, but it didn't occur that way when $N$ varied randomly for each $X_k$, like you have in your problem.

Here is a sample image showing the convergence of the algorithm (which can be shown by the covariance trace moving towards 0):
[image]

Edit: I thought I would also post a plot of the $L_{2}$ Error history per iteration. Note that this $L_{2}$ Norm computation is based on the estimated $w$ vector vs the truth one. Now, this first plot is when $N$ is constant through every $X$ vector.
[image]

This next picture is when $N$ has a different value for every $X$ based on some Gaussian random sampling. Note, truth $\bar{N}$ in this case is the mixtureCenter variable (trying to estimate the mean $N$).
[image]

As you can see, estimating $N$ when it is constant results in some better estimations than when you have a slightly different $N$ for each $X$ sample, but it still gets a decent estimate in the harder situation. To further improve the convergence rates of the solution, one could do a batch processing via "sensor" fusion techniques. Below I show similar plots as above, but using a batch of 5 random $X$ vectors:

[image: Error using Batch of 5 samples with Constant N]

[image: Error using Batch of 5 samples with Random Sampled N]

The first of these plots is for when the unknown $N$ is constant and the latter is when you are trying to estimate a mean $N$ based on random $N$ values for each $X$. Within a very small number of iterations, you can see great estimation performance in both examples.

Here is a pretty helpful link on the subject:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter

My code can be found at the following [github repository](https://github.com/choward1491/KalmanFilterParameterEstimation).

Comment: thank you for your time and efforts! You made a pretty useful and educational answer, good job. The case I was interested in, is where for each observation of X, we have a random sample of N, from a Gaussian distribution. So N is not constant. At the end, I need parameters of mean and covariance of estimated N. May I ask to include the code you used to produce the results and plots in the answer, if it's possible?

Comment: You should be able to use the estimate for $A$ and $\bar{N}$ to estimate the covariance matrix. All you end up doing is finding the random difference between unknown $N_{i}$ and $\bar{N}$ via: $Y_{i}-A*X_{i}-\bar{N} = \delta N_{i}$. Then the covariance, $Q$, is estimated via $Q = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n} \delta N_{i}\delta N_{i}^{T}$. Also, the code isn't brief so I don't know if I will post it here.

Comment: but wait...isn't Kalman filter for time series? my observations are not really time dependent and in $X_i, i$ is not time. they are only different observations from a distribution.

Comment: @Anoosh No, you can modify Kalman filters, as I have, to estimate parameters. It's growing in usage in machine learning, as well. If you notice the dynamics equation with $w$, it has steady state dynamics (plus some noise). This is a typical formulation for estimating parameters.

Comment: thank you! matlab has an implementation of kalman filter. I will try to use it for the example problem in my question.

Comment: @Anoosh sounds good! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize the answers given for this question, here I provide a visualization of different methods carried out to learn the projection matrix $A$ given clean samples $X_i$ and noisy samples $Y_i$:

[image: learning the projection matrix using different methods: first row: original matrix for 5 different cases, second row: initialization of the matrix, third row: using normal equation, directly derive the projection matrix, fourth row: linear regression using gradient descent and finally, fifth row, using kalman filtering]

In the first row we can see 5 different projection matrices ($A$) chosen to project $X$ before adding Gaussian noise $N$.

In the second row, you can find the random projections initialized to be learned via different methods.

Third and fourth rows are related to a solution suggested in [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52154/learning-parameters-of-noise-and-filter-coefficients-from-data-where-data-and-no/52412#52412).

In the  third row, using the normal equation, we directly derive the projection matrix:
$$ \hat A = (X^T \times X)^{-1} \times X^T \times Y$$

In the fourth row, a linear regression using gradient descent is used to learn the projections via $X$ and $Y$.

And finally, the last row, using kalman filtering method suggested by **choward**.

As you can observe, the GD solution and the normal equation are very similar and since in this example, $(X^T \times X)^{-1}$ is feasible to calculate, it sounds a more reasonable solution and can be done in only one step. If the dimensionality of our features were too high, then we can use the GD since both $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian.

The KF solution converges faster than GD, but can not achieve a good performance as GD, I believe.

After learning $A$, $N$ can be calculated via: $$\hat N=Y- \hat A \times X$$

and further $\hat {\mu_N}$ and $\hat {\Sigma_N}$ can be computed using $\hat N$.

Comment: Cool visual! I will have to implement a gradient descent and see how it compares. I should say that if you just try to estimate just $A$ first, the KF does better (tried it this morning). I also believe you could tune the KF to be better than the one I implemented (I didn't really tune it). But nonetheless, cool visual and result!

Comment: @choward thank you! you should try the regression solutions. I guess since my problem is much easier than a time-dependent problem with no Gaussian assumption, regression can solve it easily. Kalman should be more powerful in more difficult situation. e.g. a time serrie from an unknown distribution. 

Maybe you are right, maybe kalman also can be optimized. anyways, enjoyed a lot working on this question and learned about kalman filters power from you!

Comment: This answer was copy-pasted on [on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/52412/755) too.

Comment: @Anoosh Hey this is random at this point, but I have been doing some more advanced filtering stuff lately and improved working with Kalman Filters. I found the filter I gave you to use was not very well tuned and it can be improved. After retuning it, it performs VERY good.

Comment: @choward very good! would be glad to give it a try tho!

Comment: @Anoosh you can check out my Github again and get whatever you took from the original script I have on there. My main change was some coefficients for the Kalman filter.

Comment: @choward great! I'll give it a shot again. thanx! :)